# Simulating a keyboard's output (making a computer pose as another computer's keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, usb, simulation

I want to be able to connect a computer A's USB port to computer B's USB port so as to make computer A act as computer B's keyboard.

Any idea how I would go about doing that?

I'm not looking for a ready-made solution (though if one already exists and is open-sources I 
would not object), but for a starting point or a good resource.

I imagine I'd need to write a driver that simulates the keyboard's protocol, and I would also need to sort out the entire USB master/slave scenario.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

P.S.
I want to do it with the mouse as well, but I imagine it will be a very similar process, and I think (but I might be wildly mistaken) that starting with the keyboard will be easier.

Comment: One thing to look into might be a [BadUSB](https://hackaday.com/tag/badusb/) or a [USB Rubber Ducky](https://shop.hak5.org/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe). They simulate keyboard input very well very quickly. I'd also take a look at Seytonic's [Malduino](https://maltronics.com/collections/malduinos/products/malduino-elite).

Answer (score 12):

I am really excited to have found something that will do this from Hagstrom Electronics.  It take a serial input and sends a USB keyboard output to another PC.  If you combine this with a readily available USB to serial adaptor, then you are golden.

http://www.hagstromelectronics.com/products/usbkm232.html

I have been searching for weeks to find this, so I decided to go back to some forums and share the discovery.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Linux has support for [USB gadget mode](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/drivers/usb/gadget/Kconfig?v=2.6.11.8), but I think you need special hardware for that. I.e. the USB port in a normal PC can not do gadget mode.

An alternative is to wire an LPT port to a PS/2 keyboard input, this is technically simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If it wasn't for the USB, I'd connect the two via LAN and have a client/server C# program that emulates a keyboard / mouse (e.g. via DirectInput).

For the USB part as far as I can tell you'll need some hardware adapter. If you're into hardware development or at least unafraid of a soldering iron and some µc programming, have a look at http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/hidkeys.html where a HID stack for a small atmel chip is available for free. For this solution you'd need two atmega chips which communicate  via I²C or SPI or such.
I'd recommend electrical separation of the two pcs, too. You never know if they share the same electrical ground or not.

Comment: By electrical separation, do you mean that on the "slave's" side I should disconnect the VCC and GND, and opto-couple the D+ and D- lines?

Comment: In basic, yes, though: It's actually very difficult to electrically separate a USB connection due to the unpredictable signal directions in the D+ and D- lines. But what's very easy to do is to (e.g. optically) decouple the SPI-or-such connection between the two microcontrollers. Then each µc would be powered separately via its own USB connection.

Comment: To the dear downvoter: What's the -1 for? Please help me improve: What about my answer is wrong or off-topic?